# ServiceStack: when I throw [MyCustom]Exception in Service I'm getting "[MyCustom]Exception was unhandled by user code"

Tags: c#, exception, servicestack-bsd

In `Service` class I have `Post` method:

```
    public void Post(UpdateAdd request)
    {
        try
        {
            Service.Db.Insert(some_data);
        }
        catch (SqlException e)
        {
            switch (e.Number)
            {
                case SqlErrorNumbers.UniqueIndex: 
                    throw new UniqueIndexException();
            }
        }
    }
```

When I hit `F5` (Debug->Run) service code stops at end of catch and says: "UniqueIndexException was unhandled by user code" and in my client code I must catch general WebException not WebServiceException like doc [says here](https://github.com/ServiceStackV3/ServiceStackV3/wiki/Error-Handling#wiki-throwing-c-exceptions).

What I'm missing?

How to make that throwing new UniqueIndexException(); do not stops my code execution when run in Debug mode and how to know that UniqueIndexException() was thrown in service. InnerException of WebException is null.

Comment: Do you have "Just my code" turned on?

Comment: @MattSmith OK, turning off "Just my code" resolves first problem.